# What causes the failure to use environment variables in this Vue 3 with TypeScript app?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on an SPA with Vue 3 and TypeScript.

The app is intended to consume an API. I have the API's url and key in `src\env.js`:

```
export default {
 api_url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?",
 api_key: "somerandomkey"
}
```

In `src\views\HomeView.vue` I have:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-title">{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
    <MoviesList />
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import env from '@/env.js'
import MoviesList from '../components/MoviesList.vue';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'HomeView',

    components: {
      MoviesList
    },

    data() {
      return {
        pageTitle: "Popular Movies",
        movies: [],
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getMovies() {
        axios.get(`${env.api_url}api_key=${env.api_key}`).then(response => {
        this.movies = response.data.results;
        })
        console.log(this.movies)
      }
    }
});
</script>
```

#### The problem

The compilation fails with the error (in the terminal):

> Could not find a declaration file for module '@/env.js'.

#### Questions

1. What is causing this problem?
2. What is the  most reliable way to fix it?

Comment: `@/env.js` is not a valid name/path.

Comment: That's a typescript error, telling you that there are not types for the .js file. Either create a declaration file or turn it into a .ts file and add types to the content.

Comment: @MoritzRingler I have a declaration file named `shims-vue.d.ts`, in the `src` directory. What do I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming that the `@` is understood by your builder as the src folder and the file is found.

The error comes from TypeScript, because you import a .js file and TS does not know what types to expect from it.

I think your best two options are:

- Rename `src/env.js` to `src/env.ts` - then it is a TypeScript file and TS will infer the types automatically
- If, for some reason, you don't want to rename the file, add a declaration file (`env.d.ts`), where you give the types for the module exports manually:

```
export default {
  api_url: string,
  api_key: string
}
```